# Boto: how to ssh into multiple EC2 instances and start long-running process

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, boto

I have a script that logs into an existing Amazon EC2 instance and starts a python process using `sshclient_from_instance` like so:

```
ssh_client = sshclient_from_instance(instance,
                                 ssh_key_file='path/to/my/pem',
                                 user_name='ubuntu')
status, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.run('python myscript.py')
```

My problem is that the last line waits until it receives the status, stdout, stderr objects back from the EC2 instance. My `myscript.py` running on the EC2 instance takes several hours, and I'd like to start 20 of them on different instances in a loop.

Right now I've been killing the boto kernel manually and then restarting it for the next instance, but I can't help but wonder if there isn't a way to get out of that last line and loop over my boto script 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

how about forget boto:

Suppose you have a file with all hosts (hostname or IP address)

```
$ cat hosts
host1
host2
host3
...
```

run below command to get the job done.

```
while line host 
do
  nohup ssh -i path/to/my/pem ubuntu@$host python myscript.py &
done < hosts
```

If you know ansible, maybe you need think to use it to manage these instances with easier way.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the output of the script then you would have to launch each in a separate thread.

If you don't care about the output of the script then you can use [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) and launch the script in the background. I haven't tested this but this should give you the general idea:

```
status, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.run('sh -c "nohup python myscript.py &>/dev/null &"')
```